# MonoGame: Why doesn't my sprite render correctly when drawn several times at the same location?

Tags: c#, monogame

I'm using MonoGame 3.8.0.1641. I'm building a top-down dungeon crawler; nothing fancy. I have a top-down view of a dungeon corridor. At one spot, there are three doors leading in different directions on one tile. See image below.

[image: Screenshot of dungeon corridor showing rendering problem]

The problem is that the west door in the center doesn't render. You can see on the other side of the tile; the east half of the door renders fine. And you can see west doors do render if you look at the door to the left and the right side of the middle-east door.

I'm using the same sprite (the door sprite) in the same position and just rotating it 90° for each SpriteBatch Draw call.

If I turn off all the east doors, the west door renders fine (but then, of course, I don't have any east doors).

I render the doors in this order:

1. North door
2. East door
3. South door
4. West door

If I change the order and render the east doors last, then they don't show up!

The code for rendering the west door is below, but it's similiar to how they all are:

```
if ((tile & (uint)con.Tile.DoorWest) > 0)
{
    // Weird thing I have to do because rotating the sprite moves it one block to the left
    blockRect.X += blockRect.Width;
    
    // rotate sprite and draw it
    float rotation = (float)ConvertDegreesToRadians(90.0f);
    _spriteBatch.Draw(_doorSprite, blockRect, srcRect, Color.White,
                      rotation, origin, SpriteEffects.None, 1.0);
}
```

The sprite itself is pretty simple. It's a PNG with a transparent background. It's just a few black lines and it's the same size as a full tile:

[image: Blown up image of door tile]

I thought the transparent part of the tile might be drawing opaque, but that can't be the case because then the north door would get cut off as well.

I tried lots of other things, like playing with opacity, z-order and whatnot, but nothing makes any difference. I tried a different sprite which has a magenta background instead. While the magenta renders as transparent like it should, it displays the same erroneous rendering.

Any ideas?

Comment: But they render fine when I turn off the east doors, so surely it can't be that. I'll give it a shot, though.

Comment: Tried it, but it doesn't make a difference. I have to cast it to a float anyway, since that's what `Draw()` requires.

Comment: That line shifts the door back to the correct X position. The rotation takes place at the origin, so it rotates it out of place. That just moves it back to where it's supposed to be. All the other door renders use the same line of code, and it works. It works on all other door renders, even the west doors. It's just in this one spot where the door doesn't render. I took it out, and the west doors are all drawn out of place.

The `Rectangle` is the `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Rectangle`. It's what MonoGame uses.

Comment: By adding the C# tag, you have gotten a lot of guesses. , but without a definition for the  `blockRect` and `origin`, they are just that guesses.  Please provide more detail.  The SO standard is a minimally reproducible example (you have not met that burden). This happens a lot in Monogame questions, I am happy to answer limited information questions, below SO standards, as long as I have enough information to provide an appropriate response.

Comment: There is not enough information to give an accurate answer to this problem. The OP has been notified and given sufficient time to edit the question to provide the details required, that I have voted to close this question.

Comment: @PoulBak, You are wrong, the floating point error must accumulate to induce error. There is no accumulation in the code; there is no "repeatedly":  `rotation`  is set to a fixed value and consumed and destroyed since it falls out of scope after the `Draw()` call: no state is maintained between `Draw()` calls. Even if this was the problem, the gate would be drawn slightly askew, not missing.

Comment: Go ahead and close it, @Strom. I fixed it by just working around it. I still don't know why it behaved the way it did, but it's a moot issue now. Thanks for the comments.

And I didn't see how I could provide a minimally reproducible example. It requires MonoGame and an asset, which is hard to provide on SO.

Comment: I have MonoGame installed, and can create my own assets if needed. The requirement is in place to force you to consider the problem in minimalistic terms, and by doing that, you have a higher chance of solving it on your own, or reducing the problem so that someone is able to help.